# Как сохранить элементы QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть `QCombobox` с данными `'head','body'....` при закрытии программы эти данные пропадают. Как сохранить данные, чтобы после открытия программы они загрузились.

Думаю, что надо сохранять в файл все значения и потом загружать их. Но тогда я не знаю как получить все значения из Qcombobox. Какие есть варианты?

UPD: Элементы `ComboBox` добавляются пользователем

`self.namebuild = str(self.NameEdit.toPlainText()).capitalize()  self.SelectBuildCMB.addItem(self.namebuild)`

.При закрытии программы так как это не постоянные данные они выгружаются. Как при повторном открытии программы загрузить те данные обратно что ввёл пользователь.

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пример вашего приложения и объясните лучше куда пропадают данные? и что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit,
                             QComboBox, QApplication, QPushButton)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.fileName = 'comboBox.ini'
        if os.path.exists(self.fileName):
            with open(self.fileName, 'r') as f:
                self._listItems = f.read().strip().split('\n')   #strip().split()
        else:
            self._listItems = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5']
            
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        btn = QPushButton('Add')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.onButton)
        
        self.lbl = QLabel('Item 1', self)

        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)
        self.combo.addItems(self._listItems)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        vbox.addWidget(self.combo)

    def onActivated(self, text):
        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()
        
    def onButton(self):
        namebuilds = [
            i.strip().capitalize() for i in self.textEdit.toPlainText().split('\n') if i.strip()
        ]     
        self.combo.addItems(namebuilds)
        self.textEdit.clear()

    def closeEvent(self, event):  
        with open(self.fileName, 'w') as f:
            for i in range(self.combo.count()):
                it = self.combo.itemData(i, 0)
                f.write(f'{it}\n')   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]